# Update vaulted shopper on bluesnap

Tags: field, payment, hosted, bluesnap

I tried to update a vaulted shopper "sandbox" but it return this error:

array(1) { ["message"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["errorName"]=> string(26) "VALIDATION_GENERAL_FAILURE" ["description"]=> string(76) "Seller 636*** encountered a problem updating shopper due to incorrect input." } [1]=> array(4) { ["errorName"]=> string(26) "VALIDATION_GENERAL_FAILURE" ["code"]=> string(5) "10001" ["description"]=> string(43) "'Card Number' should be a valid Credit Card" ["invalidProperty"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(10) "cardNumber" } } } }} }

```
This is data I am sending 

$data=array(
            "paymentSources"=> array(
            "creditCardInfo" => [array(
                "pfToken"=> $Token 
            )]),

            "firstName"=>"name of shopper",
            "lastName"=> "last name of shopper",
             "vaultedShopperId"=> 23074901

            );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might mean that your Hosted Payment Fields token (`pfToken`) has not been associated with a credit card.

I encountered this same error while trying to write an integration test.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350044/testing-a-bluesnap-api-integration) question.